# Organizing items in QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, list, qt, pointers, scene

Is this a good practice to store graphic items of scene in lists? 
I know that `QGraphicsItem` has virtual method `int type()` and you can dynamically find items by type. So what I mean is that I want to store my graphic items on stack in separate lists.

```
class Scene : public QGraphicsScene
{
         public:
         // Constructors etc.
         private:
         // Store graphic items in lists by value
         QList<Carrot> m_carrots; 
         QList<Apple> m_apples;
};
```

This might sound dumb but the main concerns I have that in my current project everything is bound on using pointers and sometimes there are segmentation faults. And deleting items using

```
delete item; 
item = nullptr;
```

And I want to manage items just using let's say `m_apples.removeAt(index).`
The problem is I don't know yet what it can lead to, also the project is pretty huge, so these changes can affect other pieces of code and take a lot of time. But I think it might help in managing memory safer way.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're storing lists by value, but this has nothing to do with any stacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you store items by value, you must treat them as values and let the container manage the memory. An explicit `delete` on such an item is a bug. Qt's item classes are not copyable - thus you can:

1. Make the derived classes copyable as `QList` has to copy.
2. Use `std::list` as it doesn't need to copy.
3. Use a vector of unique pointers, e.g. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr>`.

Comment: Thanks for answer @KubaOber . What I meant to say is does anyone do things like that, avoiding pointers. I just was desperate to know whether there exists another way of utilizing objects in qt. But as I moved forward I understood that assigning parents to objects allocated on heap is working pretty well.

Comment: I do things like that all the time. It gives you smaller and faster code. Prefer storing things by value.